# Java Minecraft Color Glass

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am making a plugin that when you type /teleport you will get an inventory of 9 places in there there must be a stained glass pane that is red but i can get the stained glass pane but i can't get him red because when i try to that the name of the items are broken. the code of the red stained glass is STANED_GLASS_PANE:14
 in the code i tried this:

> ItemStack spawnItem = ItemName(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, ChatColor.AQUA + "Teleport To Spawn!");

That works fine but when i try this i doesn't work

> ItemStack spawnItem = ItemName(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE,1 , 14, ChatColor.AQUA + "Teleport To Spawn!");

or if i try this

> ItemStack spawnItem = ItemName(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, (short) 14, ChatColor.AQUA + "Teleport To Spawn!");

does not work but if i do it like this

> ItemStack spawnItem = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, (short 14);

It is red now but the item had no name i dont know how to add the name. here is my full code on this.

```
package com.jelles.plugin1.commands;

    import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
    import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
    import org.bukkit.Material;
    import org.bukkit.command.Command;
    import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
    import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
    import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
    import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
    import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
    import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;

    public class inventoryEquip implements CommandExecutor {

        public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commadLabel, String[] args) {
            if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                sender.sendMessage("You must be a player to run this command!");
                return false;
            }

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 9, "Custom Inventory");

            ItemStack spawnItem = nameItem(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, ChatColor.AQUA + "Teleport To Spawn!");
            ItemStack houseItem = nameItem(Material.APPLE, ChatColor.RED + "Teleport To A House!");
            ItemStack cloudItem = nameItem(Material.FEATHER, ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "Teleport To A Cloud!");

            inv.setItem(4, spawnItem);
            inv.setItem(5, houseItem);
            inv.setItem(3, cloudItem);

            player.openInventory(inv);

            return true;
        }

        private ItemStack nameItem(ItemStack item, String name) {
            ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
            meta.setDisplayName(name);
            item.setItemMeta(meta);
            return item;
        }

        private ItemStack nameItem(Material item, String name) {
            return nameItem(new ItemStack(item), name);
        }

    }
```

If you need anything else let me know thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to use `ItemMeta` to set the name.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `(short)` with `(byte)`, the data value is a byte, not a short.

```
ItemStack spawnItem = nameItem(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1,0,(byte) 14);
ItemMeta spawnItemMeta = spawnItem.getItemMeta();
spawnItemMeta.setName(ChatColor.AQUA+"Teleport To Spawn!");
spawnItem.setItemMeta(spawnItemMeta);
```

You also have to use `ItemMeta` to set the name and lore.

Comment: still if i do that i cant name it thats the problem i want to make it a red stained glass and give it a name :)

Comment: I fixed it @user7147407